# tag based filter in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, jquery, vector-layer

I want to filter an OpenLayers(2) vector layer based on tags. Therefore, the vector layer has a property column which can be filled by comma-seperated tags like e.g. "culture,food,park", but also only one tag e.g. "food". I want to show all features who has one tag "activated" by respective jquery controlled buttons.

with only one tag per feature it is working with the following code:

```
tags = ['school','food','park'];

activeTags = [];
function fillArrayOfFilters() {
  activeLayers = [];
  $.each(tags, function(id, tag) {
    if ($('#' + this).hasClass('active') == true) {
      activeTags.push(tags);
    };
  });
  filters = activeLayers.map(function(tag, id) {
    return new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: "tags",
        value: tag
      });
  });
}

function filter() {
  var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
    filters: filters
  });
  filterStrategy.setFilter(filter);
};
```

I know that there is a LIKE comparison in OpenLayers. But how can i use it in this case? I want something like that:

```
  new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
    property: "tags",
    value: *tag*
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a way - quite simple.
One just need to use a regular expression object as filter value:

```
  new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
    property: "tags",
    value: new RegExp(tag)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below Jsfiddle which surely helpfull to you...

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47kyN/36/)

```
function updateFilter(station_id) {
    //Put the logical filter there  

for(var id in station_id)
{
filters[id] =
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL,
        property: "id_station",
                value: station_id[id]
    });
}


filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
      filters:[filters]  });

filterStrategy.setFilter(filter);
```

}